# Divide whole numbers into X parts

Tags: php

I need to divide an integer value into x parts (dynamic) using php inside a for loop (Note:Both the number to be split and the split value are dynamic)

for eg: I have a value 127 and divide it into 2parts it would be 63 and 64.

```
$number = y; //for example is 127
$parts = x; //for example is 2


for($i=1;$i<$parts;$i++){
    //first iteration should output 63
    //second iteration should output 64 (the last iteration should be always higher is the $number is not divisible by $parts)
}
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: I can't get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example. I use the modulo operator. This works whether it's an even or odd number. You could wrap this all in a function also.

```
$x = 127;
$a = 0;
$b = 0;

$a = floor($x/2);
$b = ($x % 2) + $a;

echo "A: " . $a . "| B: " . $b; //A: 63| B: 64
```

Try it in a function.

```
    function remainders($x, $num) {
    $results = array();

    $firstOp = floor($x / $num);
    for($a = 1; $a <= $num; $a++) {
        if($a != $num) {
            $results[] = $firstOp;
        }
        else {
            if($x % 2 == 1) {
                $results[] = $firstOp + 1;
            }
            else {
                $results[] = $firstOp;
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Then you can iterate through the returned array or do what you want.

```
$splitNum = remainders(183, 4); //split the number 183 in 4 parts.

foreach($splitNum as $var) { echo $var . ", "; }
```

Comment: This way works but what I need is to do the process inside a for loop.

Comment: Why do you need it in a for loop?

Comment: Because I want to call it in as a function like splitnumber($number, $parts)

Comment: Close enough but I also need a dynamic value of $parts.. For example.. if I want to split 127 into 3 it would be 42, 42, 43. Both the number to be split and the split value are dynamic.

Comment: You could have specified that in the original post. ;) In that case, you'll need a for each loop inside of the funtion.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. I'm going to keep this function in my function repository, it might be useful later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$number = 127; //for example is 127
$parts = 3; //for example is 3
$sep = ", ";

$n=floor($number/$parts);
for($i=1;$i<=$parts;$i++){    
    if ($i==$parts) {
        $n=$number-($n*($i-1));
        $sep="";
    } 
    echo $n.$sep;        
}
```